# Instantiate Spawn Points at different positions based on the number of spawnpoints there are?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation, game-development

I'm currently creating a game in Unity where I'm trying to instantiate different spawnpoints where the game objects that my player will interact with will spawn at. The goal of the script is to make sure that the spawnpoints that get instantiated each get instantiated at different X positions above the screen with an equal distance from one to the next regardless of the amount of spawnpoints that get instantiated. However when I try to run my game nothing happens. For testing purposes I temporarly assigned a value of 4 to the size of the Transform array but this will change latter to be able to hold any value. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?  Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class BallSpawnerControl2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform[] spawnPoints = new Transform [4];
    public GameObject[] interact;
    int SpawnPoint, Interact;
    int index = 1;
    public static bool spawnAllowed;



    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {


        spawnAllowed = true;
        InvokeRepeating("SpawnAInteract", 0f, 1f);
    }

    void SpawnAInteract()
    {
        Vector2 pos = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(transform.position);
        double TotaLBalls = spawnPoints.Length * 1.8f; // Total length of all balls at same X/Y position 
        double TotalLspaces = 1.0f - TotaLBalls; // Length left for spaces
        int Nspaces = spawnPoints.Length + 1; // Nr of spaces 
        double Length1space = TotalLspaces / Nspaces;


        for (int d = 0; d < spawnPoints.Length; d++)
        {
            Vector3 SpawnPos = spawnPoints[d].position;
            double spawnPosX = 0.0 + Length1space * d;
            SpawnPos.x = (float)spawnPosX;
            pos.x = SpawnPos.x;
            pos.y = 1.3f;

            Instantiate(spawnPoints[d], pos,
                       Quaternion.identity);


        }

        if (spawnAllowed)
        {

            { 
                   for (int i = 0; i < spawnPoints.Length; i++)
                   {
                    if (index % 100 != 0)
                    {
                        Interact = 1;
                        Instantiate(interact[Interact], pos,
                        Quaternion.identity);
                     index++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Interact = 0;
                        Instantiate(interact[Interact], pos,
                        Quaternion.identity);
                        index++;
                    }
                   }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Edited version:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class BallSpawnerControl2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform[] spawnPoints;
    public GameObject[] interact;
    int SpawnPoint, Interact;
    int index = 1;
    public static bool spawnAllowed;
    //

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        Vector2 pos = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(transform.position);
        double TotaLBalls = spawnPoints.Length * 1.8f; // Total length of all balls at same X/Y position 
        double TotalLspaces = 1.0f - TotaLBalls; // Length left for spaces
        int Nspaces = spawnPoints.Length + 1; // Nr of spaces 
        double Length1space = TotalLspaces / Nspaces; // 



        //double XPosition = 0.0 + Length1space * i;
        //Use variable position to assign positions to SpawnPoints based on value of ScoreValue and use position value to influence the movement of balls
        if (ScoreScript.scoreValue < 5)
        {
            Transform[] spawnPoints = new Transform[4];

            for (int d = 0; d < spawnPoints.Length ; d++)
            {

                // Use instantiate to duplicate spawnpoints
                Vector3 SpawnPos = spawnPoints[d].position;
                double spawnPosX = 0.0 + Length1space * d;
                SpawnPos.x = (float)spawnPosX;
                pos.x = SpawnPos.x;
                pos.y = 1.3f;

                Instantiate(spawnPoints[d], pos,
                           Quaternion.identity);



            }

        }


        /*  if (pos.x < 0.0) Debug.Log("I am left of the camera's view.");
      if (1.0 < pos.x) Debug.Log("I am right of the camera's view.");
      if (pos.y < 0.0) Debug.Log("I am below the camera's view.");
      if (1.0 < pos.y) Debug.Log(pos); */

        spawnAllowed = true;
        InvokeRepeating("SpawnAInteract", 0f, 1f);
    }

    void SpawnAInteract()
    {


        if (spawnAllowed)
        {

            { 
                   for (int i = 0; i < spawnPoints.Length; i++)
                   {
                    if (index % 100 != 0)
                    {
                        Interact = 1;
                        Instantiate(interact[Interact], spawnPoints[i].position,
                        Quaternion.identity);
                     index++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Interact = 0;
                        Instantiate(interact[Interact], spawnPoints[i].position,
                        Quaternion.identity);
                        index++;
                    }
                   }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you fill you spawnPoints array ? Do you have any errors in your console ?

Comment: Yes I have, but I want a way to fill the array in the script not in the Unity inspector. Also even if I fill the array in Unity it still doesn't work properly

Comment: To fill in script you have to create new transform and fill your array with it. How does it work now and how do you want it ?

Comment: I want the array to be filled with 4 transforms that I will use as the position from which to instantiate other game objects of type interact. If the scorevalue is < 5. if the scorevalue is bigger then five I will have more transforms. I slightly edited my code and now I'm getting the error that my object reference isn't set to an instance of a game object. I added the edited version after my previous code

Comment: I think you spawnPoints array contains 4 null transforms. you need to create them to fill your array.

Comment: How would I create them in my script?